# Run-Time Error for Chanukah Problem on Kattis

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error

I solved the Chanukah problem from kattis in my IDE and it works perfectly, but when I'm submitting it on kattis, I get a runtime error.

This is the code I'm trying to submit, which works perfectly fine in my local IDE and also on replit.

```
def chanukah():
    sets = int(input())
    dict = {}
    for k in range(sets):
        days = int(input())
        total = (days * (days + 1) // 2) + days
        dict[k + 1] = total

    for key, value in dict.items():
        print(key, value)


chanukah()
```

I encountered a similar issue on a previous problem, and what I did to fix it was adding extra variables assigning the inputs as `int` after getting the input from the user, instead of converting the input into `int` right in the input line, like you can see below, but this time it doesn't make the trick and kattis doesn't like my solution.

```
def chanukah():
    sets = input()
    dict = {}
    sts = int(sets)
  
    for k in range(sts):
        days = input()
        dys = int(days)
        total = (dys * (dys + 1) // 2) + dys
        dict[k + 1] = total

    for key, value in dict.items():
        print(key, value)


chanukah()
```

Why is kattis throwing a run-time error and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`k` was used as an auto-increment for the solution, but actually it had to be manually inserted for each prompt in the `for loop` by the user.

You can find below the correct solution to the `Chanukah Challenge` accepted on kattis.com, and the submission details, as well:

```
def chanukah():
    sets = int(input())
    dict = {}
    for k in range(sets):
        inp = input().split(" ")
        increment = int(inp[0])
        days = int(inp[1])
        total = (days * (days + 1) // 2) + days
        dict[increment] = total

    for key, value in dict.items():
        print(key, value)


chanukah()
```

[Submission Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jrBR.png)

Comment: Glad you worked it out. You can simplify the solutiion a bit as shown [here](https://github.com/ggorlen/kattis/blob/main/chanukah.py)--there's no need for the dict. Also, be careful when naming a variable `dict` as it overwrites a builtin function.